# Making container to occupy same space for components in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

In my swing application I have to create a number panel for taking user input. The required numbers can change according to requirement (For example at one place it contain numbers 1-90, at another place it contains 1-36 numbers). 
My problem is that at both places the space in the bottom of the panel and on the right side changes when number of buttons change (from 36 to 90). How can I manage that?
I am sending the code for the reference.

```
public class TestNumberPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton[] btns;
    private static int NUM_BTNS = 42;
    private int initialValue = 1;
    private int gridRows = 6;
    private int gridCols = 7;

    public JButton[] getNumBtns() {
        return btns;
    }

    public TestNumberPanel(final int btns) {
        NUM_BTNS = btns;
        if (NUM_BTNS == 42) {
            gridRows = 6;
            gridCols = 7;
        } else if (NUM_BTNS == 90) {
            gridRows = 10;
            gridCols = 9;
        } else if (NUM_BTNS == 36) {
            gridRows = 6;
            gridCols = 6;
        }
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        btns = new JButton[NUM_BTNS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BTNS; i++) {
            btns[i] = new JButton();
            btns[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
            btns[i].setText(String.valueOf(initialValue));
            add(btns[i]);
            initialValue++;
        }
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 370));
        // setBackground(ScreenColor.COLOR_WHITE);
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 0));
        // GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(gridRows, gridCols, 5, 5);
        // gridLayout.minimumLayoutSize(this);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(gridRows, gridCols, 5, 5));
        // setLayout(gridLayout);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFrame() {
            {
                try {
                    add(new TestNumberPanel(36));
                    pack();
                    setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Any suggestion for improvement in this code also will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Any suggestion for improvement in this code also will be appreciated"* - Don't use `setPreferredSize`, ensure that your initialising your UI within the context of the EDT, see [intial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for details

Comment: Is the user choosing one of many (`JSpinner`), or one or more of many (`JList`)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson- As per the requirement user can choose any numbers from the given numbers (at one screen I have to give option to choose from 1-90, at another 1-36 etc). User can not pick duplicate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer- I have to fix the size of the panel (In fact I have to add this panel at different required screen). And for that I have to provide a fixed size to this panel. Main method in this is for test only, I have initialized on EDT at actual place.

Comment: *"In fact I have to add this panel at different required screen"* is a damn good reason not to be messing with the preferred size, you don't control the factors that affect a components size requirements, that's what the layout manager is good at

Comment: @MadProgrammer- But on every screen required size of this panel is same.